# str_extract specific patterns

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to extract strings having same patterns from the text

[The Tragedy of Romeo and Juliet by William Shakespeare](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt)

```
library(readr)

txt <- read_file('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt')
```

Text example:

> Scene I.\r\nVerona. A public place.\r\n\r\nEnter Sampson and Gregory
>   (with swords and bucklers) of the house\r\nof Capulet.
>   ...
>   Scene II.\r\nA Street.\r\n\r\nEnter Capulet, County Paris, and [Servant]
>   -the Clown.\r\n\r\n\r\n  Cap.

I want to extract

> Verona. A public place.
>   A Street

I tried with

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(txt, "Scene\\s[IV]+\\.\\s\\s\\b[A-Z]+\\b")
```

It didn't work.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_extract_all(gsub("(Scene.*?)\r\n","\\1 ",txt),"Scene.*")
[[1]]
 [1] "Scene I. Verona. A public place."                                    
 [2] "Scene II. A Street."                                                 
 [3] "Scene III. Capulet's house."                                         
 [4] "Scene IV. A street."                                                 
 [5] "Scene V. Capulet's house."                                           
 [6] "Scene I. A lane by the wall of Capulet's orchard."                   
 [7] "Scene II. Capulet's orchard."                                        
 [8] "Scene III. Friar Laurence's cell."                                   
 [9] "Scene IV. A street."                                                 
[10] "Scene V. Capulet's orchard."                                         
[11] "Scene VI. Friar Laurence's cell."                                    
[12] "Scene I. A public place."                                            
[13] "Scene II. Capulet's orchard."                                        
[14] "Scene III. Friar Laurence's cell."                                   
[15] "Scene IV. Capulet's house"                                           
[16] "Scene V. Capulet's orchard."                                         
[17] "Scene I. Friar Laurence's cell."                                     
[18] "Scene II. Capulet's house."                                          
[19] "Scene III. Juliet's chamber."                                        
[20] "Scene IV. Capulet's house."                                          
[21] "Scene V. Juliet's chamber."                                          
[22] "Scene I. Mantua. A street."                                          
[23] "Scene II. Verona. Friar Laurence's cell."                            
[24] "Scene III. Verona. A churchyard; in it the monument of the Capulets."
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your answer, Onyambu!
Then, how about
`txt <- readLines('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt', encoding='UTF-8')`?
The txt has line, so your code is didn't work.

Comment: With thisone, you have read the file as lines. You therefore have to be able to pick only those with the name scene and their succeeding rows. eg `t(matrix(txt[c(rbind(grep("Scene",txt),grep("Scene",txt)+1))],2))` should work. But will give two columns. You can paste the columns together of course